# AWS SNS Issue: Unknown error attempting to reach phone

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Our Project is in Norway and our all customers also. We are using AWS SNS for sending Transactional SMS to the customers.

In Norway Mobile numbers simple text SMS receive but with link SMS not receiving to customer. We debugged the using cloud watch and saw the below error message.

**"Unknown error attempting to reach phone"**

Message Format: Velkommen til name.com. Klikk på lenken nedenfor for å logge inn. {{link}}

Error Log:

```
{
"notification": {
    "messageId": "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx",
    "timestamp": "2020-11-11 14:20:28.521"
},
"delivery": {
    "phoneCarrier": "Telenor Norge AS",
    "mnc": 1,
    "numberOfMessageParts": 1,
    "destination": "+000000000",
    "priceInUSD": 0.00000,
    "smsType": "Transactional",
    "mcc": 000,
    "providerResponse": "Unknown error attempting to reach phone",
    "dwellTimeMs": 000,
    "dwellTimeMsUntilDeviceAck": 0000
},
"status": "FAILURE"
```

}

Code in Laravel:

```
$sns = app('Sns');
$sns->publish([
   'PhoneNumber' => {{number}},
   'Message' => {{message}},
   'MessageAttributes' => [
        'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType' => [
             'DataType' => 'String',
             'StringValue' => 'Transactional',
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Can you share your code for sending the SMS via SNS?  Also, could you post the entire log entry?

Comment: @hephalump edit my question.

Comment: We are facing the same issue when using SMS subscription for alarms in SNS